# "in" or "on", which is the right preposition?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is gramatically correct:

'Center for Research **on/in** Geopolitics of Europe'.

My natural instinct says to use 'on'. Tell me if I'm wrong; and if so, why.

Comment: If you consider *into* instead, your instinct to use *on* may no longer be so strong.

Comment: It makes no sense either way. Just another scheme to collect grant money.

Comment: @Ricky No grant proposition without the right preposition.

Comment: @Kris: Bingo! ...

Comment: Related: [“seminar on” or “seminar in”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424853).

Answer (score -1):

How about

> The Center for European Geopolitical Research

Comment: Robert, this hasn't answered the question. The OP wasn't asking for an alternative, they were asking about whether *in* or *on* is correct.

Comment: Yes; a wonderful suggestion – which doesn't address the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

You perform research on something, not in something.

For example, "He was performing research on penguins in Antarctica.".

"He was performing research in penguins..." would have very different connotations.

Your instinct to use "on" is correct. "In" is only applicable with the addition of something like "in the field" or "in the area" - both of which connotate a location. Without those modifiers, the correct grammar is what the research is focused "on".

Comment: Welcome to our site. Your answer is heading in the right direction, but without any supporting evidence, it's simply an opinion. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference hyperlinked to the source. You can add this detail by using the [edit] link; for further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Answer (score -2):

"Center for Research **in** Geopolitics of Europe"

"Geopolitics of Europe" is a subject of study. The center undertakes research **in** the field/subject area/specialization of "Geopolitics of Europe."

HTH.